# Can't find other port on ssh, other than 22 (i.e. - 23)

Tags: ssh, remote-access

Using ssh remotely, I can ask my desktop at home (from school or wherever), but I can't access my server, also at home.

When I'm at my home, I can access both when I'm on the wireless network, oddly. Also, using Putty or an ssh iOS app, I *can* access both, so I know it must be the `ssh -p23 (ip.address.here)` is where the issue lies.

I've searched up and down, but don't know how to replicate my exact issue in a search engine.

Best and many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to access 2 devices remotely.
You maybe able to change the Port Forwarding in your router at home and open the fire wall.

Leave the Desktop as is I assume port 22 = 22.

For the Server pick any port then map it back to its IP on Port 22 on your home network.
So your router should have have incoming port mapped to IP address and port number in port forwarding section, if by any chance just have DMZ to open a computer to the Internet then you may need to buy a Gaming Router check port forwarding ability first before purchase.

You will also need your computers on **Fixed IP's** this is by raising the DHCP starting range slightly to allow it and set fixed ip's on computers, this so that normal devices still can get a automatic connection.

Comment: I have a fixed IP on both desktop and sever. The router is configured to forward both throughout deferent ports- desktop on default 22 and server on 23. My iOS ssh app as well as Putty will connect to port 23, and thus my server, but 'ssh -p23 (IP)' will not.